# C++11 multicast delegate implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, delegates

I want to add delegates to my game engine. I'm used to them in c# and now I can't live without them.

I have seen several implementations here and on external sources but they are not multicast. The delegate is just allowed to store one listener at a time. Do anybody know of any good implementation in memory/performance terms with += and -= support? I have tried writting mine using variadic templates but I'm not there yet.

Edit: This is what I have come with until now:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class Delegate
{
public:
   Delegate() =default;
   ~Delegate() = default;

   template<typename U>
   Delegate& operator += (const U &func)
   {
        _listeners.push_back(std::function<void(Args...)>(func));
        return *this;
   }

   template<typename Class, typename Method>
   Delegate& operator += (const std::function<void(Args...)> func)
   {
        _listeners.push_back(func);
        return *this;
   }

   void operator() (Args... params)
   {
        for (auto listener : _listeners)
        {
            listener(params...);
        }
   }

   private:
       std::list<std::function<void(Args...)>> _listeners;
};
```

It is working really well. Here you can see how to use it:

```
Delegate<std::string> del;
del += std::bind(&GameScene::print, this, std::placeholders::_1);
del += [](const std::string& str) { log(str.c_str()); };
del("text");
```

I know I will use the std::bind version almost all the time because this is used in a event messaging system and instances will subscribe to the delegate using a class method (by class method I am not refering to static method but a method of the class). Is there anyway to improve the std::bind part? I think it is a bit ugly and annoying when you have to add some funcions with placeholders, etc...

Cheers.

Comment: No, This implementation is not multicast. This is one of the external sources I checked before asking.

Comment: Would be pretty easy to implement, especially with C++11... Have you tried something, rather than searching for an existing implementation?

Comment: Well, I got stuck with the variadic templates. Anyway I'm playing with them at this precise moment :).

Comment: You can also take a look at `std::function`, which can be stored in a `std::vector`, for instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, a naive C++ 11 implementation could look like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class Foo
{
    public:

        std::vector< std::function< void() > > onSomething;
};

int main( void )
{
    Foo f;

    f.onSomething.push_back( [&] { /* Do something... */ } );
    f.onSomething.push_back( [&] { /* Do something else... */ } );

    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of `std::function`, which allows to store lambdas in a `vector`.
You'll then be able to iterate through the vector, and execute each lambda.

Then, of course, operator overloading and thread safety if needed... But this should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks. The main problem I am having is "templatizing" the std::function to pass the template class params.

Comment: Ok, I got the call signature std::function<void(T...)>>. Really great feature this variadic templates. As you suggested was fairly trivial when you understand the variadic thing :). THanks again for your time.

Comment: I was actually editing my answer, but nice to see you figured it out... : )